# Fail to integrate scss in my rollup build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, rollup, rollupjs

#### What I try to achieve

I'm trying to create a little library for private use - basically just splitting up some code into lib (product) and app (project) code.

All my source code lives in `/src` folder which contains `React, TypeScript and SCSS` code. It would be great, if I can use the SCSS imports directly in React like: `import './_button.scss';`

I have another SCSS file: `src/style/_main.scss` it includes some mixins, global styles, resets etc.

#### Config files

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import url from '@rollup/plugin-url';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss';
import { format, parse } from 'path';
import pkg from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };

const getTypesPath = (jsFile) => {
    const pathInfo = parse(jsFile);
    return format({
        ...pathInfo,
        base: '',
        dir: `${pathInfo.dir}/types`,
        ext: '.d.ts',
    });
};

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: pkg.main,
                format: 'cjs',
                interop: 'compat',
                exports: 'named',
                sourcemap: true,
                inlineDynamicImports: true,
            },
            {
                file: pkg.module,
                format: 'esm',
                exports: 'named',
                sourcemap: true,
                inlineDynamicImports: true,
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            resolve({ browser: true }),
            commonjs({ extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] }),
            typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.build.json' }),
            url(),
            scss({
                failOnError: true
            }),
            json(),
            terser(),
        ],
        external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    },
    {
        input: getTypesPath(pkg.module ?? pkg.main),
        output: [{ file: pkg.types, format: 'esm' }],
        plugins: [dts()],
    },
];
```

My tsconfig.build.json looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./types",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./types",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

#### Where I struggle

The main issue right now is, that it imports my SCSS file in the definition file e.g. `button.d.ts` looks like:

```
import type { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import type { IButtonProps } from './button.type';
import './_button.scss';
export declare const Button: FunctionComponent<IButtonProps>;
```

```
[!] RollupError: Could not resolve "./_button.scss" from "build/esm/types/button/button.d.ts"
```

Which is indeed a problem, but how can I fix it?

I also get the error:

```
Error:
        @use rules must be written before any other rules.
  ╷
4 │ @use 'src/style/util/mixin';
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  stdin 4:1  root stylesheet
```

But it does not really make a lot of sense, since my `_button.scss` partial has this written on the first line.

#### My Question

How do I make it work so that I can use SCSS in my library? The best case would be that I don't have to touch my original code. I just want to transpile/bundle it so I can use it somewhere else. Any advice?

Comment: I could exclude `/\.sass$/` using "external" this will make my build work, but when I use the library on the project side, it fails to resolve these .scss files. They should still be bundled with the package or rather the individual components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of probing, I finally made it work.

The issue was, that it bundled all my sass styles and it did not take into account, that I am using the new `@use` module syntax. Because everything got concatenated into one big file, `@use` syntax got placed in the middle of the file resulting in an error. Apparently, only the old `@import` syntax is properly supported by `rollup-plugin-scss` - or I was just too incapable of making it work.

So I switched to the https://anidetrix.github.io/rollup-plugin-styles/
library to process the files. All I had to do is to use the `styles` plugin and I set `mode: 'inject'` it then injected the styles into my `[esm|cjs]/index.js` file. Upon importing the lib in the app and starting it, the styles got applied.

Besides, I also had to externalize the imports from the `index.d.ts`.

The updated config file:

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import url from '@rollup/plugin-url';
import { format, parse } from 'path';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import styles from 'rollup-plugin-styles';
import pkg from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };

const getTypesPath = (jsFile) => {
    const pathInfo = parse(jsFile);
    return format({
        ...pathInfo,
        base: '',
        dir: `${pathInfo.dir}/types`,
        ext: '.d.ts',
    });
};

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: pkg.main,
                format: 'cjs',
                interop: 'compat',
                exports: 'named',
                sourcemap: true,
                inlineDynamicImports: true,
            },
            {
                file: pkg.module,
                format: 'esm',
                exports: 'named',
                sourcemap: true,
                inlineDynamicImports: true,
            },
        ],
        external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
        plugins: [
            external(),
            resolve({
                browser: true,
            }),
            url(),
            styles({
                mode: 'inject'
            }),
            json(),
            commonjs({
                extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
            }),
            typescript({
                tsconfig: './tsconfig.build.json',
            }),
            terser(),
        ],
    },
    {
        input: getTypesPath(pkg.module ?? pkg.main),
        output: [
            {
                file: pkg.types,
                format: 'esm',
            },
        ],
        external: [/\.(sass|scss|css)$/] /* ignore style files */,
        plugins: [dts()],
    },
];
```